# Redirect/Render a pdf to an iframe using ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe

This is my view

```
<div style="width:10%;float:left;margin-bottom:357px">
<%= form_for(:img, method: "post", url: {action: "printer"},:target => "frame") do |f| %>
    <input type="hidden" id="image_attach" name="image_attach">
<%= f.submit "Preview", {:id => "submit"} %>
<%end%>
</div>
<div style="width:45%;float:left">
<iframe id="frame" name="frame"height="600px" width="630px" src="<%=%>"></iframe>
</div>
```

What should I put in the source?

This is my controller

```
def printer
@image_file1=params[:image_attach]
@posts = Post.all
render(:action =>"printing.pdf",:image => @image_file1)
end

def printing
@image_file1=params[:image_attach]
@posts = Post.all
redirect_to(:layout => "frame")
end

end
```

Without iframe it works properly but with iframe nothing appears in the iframe...

please help

Answer (score 1):

An `<iframe>` element is used to embed another web page. The description from [these mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) says:

> The HTML `<iframe>` Element (or HTML inline frame element) represents a
>   nested browsing context, effectively embedding another HTML page into
>   the current page.

The source for your iframe should be the url for the page you intend to display.

It's not entirely clear why you are doing this - perhaps you should check out [some other options for PDF rendering](http://mileszs.com/wicked-pdf-plugin/).

Comment: I  have done a similar thing is JSP.I am new to ror so dont know how to get it...In java i used to pass the the pdf page directly..

Comment: If you want this in an iframe, you first need to make sure the pdf renders at a unique url itself. Then use that url for the `src` attribute in your iframe.

Comment: I will tell u wat i need..I select an image and pass I want to preview it on d same page using iframe...So i send the selected image to the controller and from the controller i send this image to the pdf as a param..so the param is causing the problem,as there wud be diff images and param value wud change,hence the url wud also change...could u suggest me another idea?

Comment: It sounds like you want to generate a pdf on the client side. Have a look at this: http://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Comment: Thnx for d suggestion..I went thru it,but i feel there r too many libraries that i will need to import(not sure if i m right on this,or else u cud tell me which are the libraries i need from these set of lib).. i just need to pass the image,so just for that getting too many libraries will require more memory..I would have used if it required a single library..